# Nagios emails not received even when notification is fired poperly

Tags: nagios

After enabling detailed debugging, I can see that Nagios is firing notifications properly.. Here is what I see in nagios.logs

```
[1430915423] SERVICE ALERT: test;Check node port;CRITICAL;HARD;4;Connection refused
[1430915423] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: abhishek;test;Check node port;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;Connection refused
[1430915423] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: root;test;Check node port;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;Connection refused
```

However, I do not receive emails at the specified contact.. I am using SSMTP..
It is working fine as well.. This command works -

```
ssmtp abc@xxx.com
```

Therefore, either 2 things can happen -

```
notify-service-by-email
```

is not working OR some security check is filtering out such emails (this should not happen as I am sending emails from my email address).. Can any one suggest how to debug this..?

EDIT - Here is my **notify-service-by-email** command -

```
define command{
        command_name    notify-service-by-email
        command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$\n" | /usr/bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Service Alert: $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue..

sSMTP was working properly.. Tested it with this command -

```
ssmtp -s abcd@xxx.com
```

Enabled `DEBUG` logs to find out that `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` did not have sufficient permission..

The file was owned by `root` instead of `nagios` user

Hope this helps someone..